# Migrating to Angular 8 (replacing old ViewChild)

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I am migrating to Angular 8 and I have the ViewChild decorator in lots of places which is very annoying to replace one by one, I want to create a regular expression to replace the old syntax in Visual Studio Code:

```
@ViewChild("someElement") element1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("anotherElement") element2: ElementRef;
```

to

```
@ViewChild("someElement", {static: false}) element1: ElementRef;
@ViewChild("anotherElement", {static: false}) element2: ElementRef;
```

I am fried using regular expressions, any help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Use ng update, and it will do that for you. https://update.angular.io/

Comment: It is a NativeScript project with Angular support, can't use 'ng update' for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regexp below to catch and group your element names the put those values into the new string.

Find

```
\@ViewChild\(\"(.*)\"\) (.*): ElementRef; 
// (.*) groups all characters in between (" -- ") and ") -- : ElementRef
```

Replace

```
@ViewChild("$1", { static: false }) $2: ElementRef;
// puts found groupings in respective places
```

Answer (score 1):

For vscode

```
Find=> @ViewChild\('.*'\) .*: ElementRef;

ReplaceBy=> @ViewChild('$1', { static: false }) $2: ElementRef;

Find=> @ViewChild\('(.*)', \{ read: (.*) \}\)
 
ReplaceBy=> @ViewChild('$1', { read: $2, static: false })
```

Comment: @ViewChild\('.*'\) .*: ElementRef;

Comment: @ViewChild\('(.*)'\) (.*): ElementRef;

Comment: Please click [edit] under your aswer and move everything into the answer that should be in the answer. Could you also please add some explanation that might help people understand your answer better.